# gcc version numbers do not increase with release date?

Tags: gcc

I was taking a look at https://gcc.gnu.org/releases.html and saw that the GCC version numbers aren't increasing monotonically with respect to the date unlike most products where the most recent version has the largest version number.

e.g., GCC 8.5 was released 5/14/21, and 11.1 4/27/21.

Why are the version numbers for gcc structured this way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on reading how they format their version numbers, it seems like its because each major release ends up as a branch with their own number of fixes rather then features. There may be reasons on why you would want to stay on the 8.x  branch rather then 11.x branch due to compatibility issues, which is why they release fixes for older branches. You can read more [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/develop.html#num_scheme). Hopes this helps clear things up!